# signing assemblies on windows mobile device

Tags: windows, mobile, assemblies, sign

HI

I have created an application for my windows mobile 6.0 device and I need to sign it so that the user can download updates without having to select  that they trust the publisher

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing here but I created the following files on the command line

- .pfx using pvk2pfx
- .spc using cert2spc
- .cer using makecert
- .pvk using makecert

and signed all the dll's and exe in my application using signtool sign

I then copied the certificates to my mobile device clicked on them and installed them
then copied my signed assemblies to the device but when I run the application I'm still being asked if I wish to run the application from an unknown and untrusted publisher

if anybody has any suggestions on how to get this working I'd be very grateful
Thanks
colm

Answer (score 0):

Take the certificate that you've signed the application with and place it in the trusted store on the device.

Assuming you're using Visual Studio you can run the Device Security Manager, which will allow you to easily install the certificate on the device.

Note that you only need to place the .cer file, not the entire .pfx on the device.